# I have just one chapter in my appendix, how to avoid the double "appendix"

Tags: appendix

I have only one chapter in my appendix, and I am not sure what to name it. If I name it appendix, it writes "appendix" twice. Are there any best practices in that case? I mean I have some sections in my appendix, but making them their own chapter seems wrong. And they don't have much in common other than "they would have disturbed the flow of the main text if I placed it inside" (i.e. assorted random stuff)

[image]

Comment: Depending on the class in use, I'd either use `\chapter*{Appendix}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}` or `\addchap{Appendix}`.

Comment: I would replace `\chapter{Appendix}` with `\chapter{Additional Results}` -- or something similar that informs the reader about what the appendix is all about.